# ipfs-http-client cat sometimes return incomplete file

Tags: ipfs, ipfs-http-client

I use `ipfs-http-client` to upload and retrieve my file.  The following creates the client and uploads an image in base64 string:

```
import { create } from "ipfs-http-client";
let client = create("/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/5001");
let file = await client.add(somebase64imagestring);
```

Below is how I retrieve the file given the CID

```
let iter = client.cat(imageCID);
for await (let img of iterable) {
  const imgStr = Buffer.from(img).toString();
}
```

The problem is intermittent.  Sometimes, I get the full base64 string in `imgStr` which is 19.9kb.  Sometimes, I only get a portion of it like 11.8kb where the first few characters are missing.  Even if I `await` on the `client.cat` which the VSCode highlights as no effect, and even if I do `client.cat(imageCID, {offset: 0})`, still the returned image string is sometimes complete, and sometimes missing the first few parts.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `iter` part may return the image in chunks, so I concat the incoming chunks instead:

```
let imgStr = "";
let iter = client.cat(imageCID);
for await (let img of iterable) {
  imgStr += Buffer.from(img).toString();
}
```

Now, I am able to get the complete image string. :)